# Getting Icon to show up in React - Ternary Expression

Tags: reactjs, jsx, ternary-operator

I'm trying to add this line of JSX in a ternary expression so that whenever I hover over the song-number-column, I can have the play icon pop up in place of that column.

You can see the line of JSX in context towards the bottom of the code. There are within the td tags.

Currently, it is giving me a Parsing error: Unterminated regular expression and pointing to the ending span tag.

I have looked elsewhere and am not sure how to resolve this error.

```
<span className="ion-md-play"> { true ? this.state.hoverOn === <col 
id="song-number-column" /> : null </span>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import albumData from './../data/albums';

class Album extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);

 const album = albumData.find( album => {
   return album.slug === this.props.match.params.slug
 });

 this.state = {
   album: album,
   currentSong: album.songs[0],
   isPlaying: false
 };

 this.audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
 this.audioElement.src = album.songs[0].audioSrc;
 }

 play() {
  this.audioElement.play();
  this.setState({ isPlaying: true });
 }

 pause() {
  this.audioElement.pause();
  this.setState({ isPlaying: false });
 }

 setSong(song) {
  this.audioElement.src = song.audioSrc;
  this.setState({ currentSong: song });
 }

 handleSongClick(song) {
  const isSameSong = this.state.currentSong === song;
   if (this.state.isPlaying && isSameSong) {
     this.pause();
  } else {
   if (!isSameSong) { this.setSong(song); }
     this.play();
  }
 }

  hoverOn(song) {
    this.setState({isMouseEnter: song });

  };

  hoverOff(song) {
    this.setState({isMouseLeave: null})
  };

  render() {
   return (
    <section className="album">
    <section id="album-info">
    <img id="album-cover-art" src={this.state.album.albumCover} alt= . 
    {this.state.album.title}/>
     <div className="album-details">
  <h1 id="album-title">{this.state.album.title}</h1>
  <h2 className="artist">{this.state.album.artist}</h2>
  <div id="release-info">{this.state.album.releaseInfo}</div>
  </div>
  </section>
   <table id="song-list">

   <colgroup>
    <col id="song-number-column" />
    <col id="song-title-column" />
    <col id="song-duration-column" />
  </colgroup>

  <tbody>
  {this.state.album.songs.map((song, index) =>
    <tr className = "song"
      key = {index}
        onClick = {() => this.handleSongClick(song)}
          onMouseEnter = {() => this.hoverOn(song)}
            onMouseLeave = {() => this.hoverOff(song)}>
    <td>

    <span className="ion-md-play"> { true ? this.state.hoverOn === <col id="song-number-column" /> : null </span>

    </td>
    <td key='number'   > {index + 1}  </td>
    <td key='title'    > {song.title} </td>
    <td key='duration' > {song.duration} </td>

    </tr>
  )}
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </section>
 );
}
}

export default Album;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your ternary expression is malformed. replace

```
<span className="ion-md-play"> { true ? this.state.hoverOn === <col id="song-number-column" /> : null </span>
```

with

```
<span className="ion-md-play"> { this.state.hoverOn === true ? (<col id="song-number-column" />) : null </span>
```

I also added parentheses around the jsx expression. It's not always necessary but there are some quirks with jsx so many people say to always put parens around it.

Comment: it is still giving me the same error and pointing to the same ending span tag

Comment: oh, oops I noticed the ternary expression but missed the missing } :P

Comment: any idea as to why the icon is not showing up whenever I hover over the songNumber or index?

Answer (score 1):

Is it less `}` ?

You can try below code.

```
<span className="ion-md-play"> { this.state.hoverOn ? (<col id="song-number-column" />) : null } </span>
```

Comment: Nice, that end curly bracket makes it run, but whenever I hover over the songnumber on the page, it's not changing to the icon.

Comment: I can't find `hoverOn` in you component's state,So  I think it always has undefined.

Comment: isn't it being called in the ternary statement? and it's been defined in the hoverOn function above?

Comment: Umm....`hoverOn` function defined `isMouseEnter` in component's state not `hoverOn`.

Comment: You can try modify the contents of `hoverOn` and `hoverOff` into `this.setState({hoverOn: true });` and `this.setState({hoverOn: null });`

Comment: still doesn't change it, but isn't isMouseEnter and isMouseLeave built in methods? and i changed it to onMouseEnter/onMouseLeave, the proper way to write them out. I added the right icon script in the index.js as well, so it should be linked to the icon library correctly

Comment: First of all, The focus is on 「`hoverOn` is not defined in component's state」,So `this.state.hoverOn` always is undefined.

Comment: You must defined or set `hoverOn` in component's state, Like as `this.state ={album:album,};` or `this.setState({ isPlaying: true });`.